# Django compressor issue - media assets from the forms.py won't update in the front-end django template

Tags: python, django

We are currently experiencing an issue with the Django compressor: We have an app that has forms.py and its media assets from the forms.py won't update in the frontend django template (only stuff inside the django compress tag won't update). This problem came about when we initially included external files in the static files media asset in forms.py, but that lead to problems with django compressor not being able to compress and access via our Cloudfront CDN. We changed that and now, it's stuck there, meaning it won't refresh with our newer local static files (we changed external file links to local static in the Media class inside forms.py). We have flushed our Redis node, done cloudfront invalidations, compressed again, collectstatic, terminated and started new instance within elasticbeanstalk. Has anyone had experience a similar issue and / or has any solutions? Many Thanks!!

Our architecture:
Elasticbeanstalk. (amazon's linux ec2 instance, python)
RDS (postgres database)
Elasticache (Redis)